# How to convert a boolean to an integer in SOLR?

Tags: java, sorting, solr, lucene, schema

I maintain a store that contains listings, some of them are premium members.  I'm trying to get the premium members within a range of 25 km on top of the search results, the rest of the listings are ordered by nearest vicinity.

To indicate that a listing is premium, I have defined the boolean field listing_premium.

```
<field name="listing_premium" type="boolean" indexed="true" stored="true" />
```

It'd be easy if I could use this boolean in a sort clause by mapping the distance to the query (listing_location) and multiplying it with the integer representing the boolean (true = 1, false = 0)

The following does not work as listing_premium is a boolean...

```
&sort=mul(map(geodist(listing_location),0.0001,25,1,0),listing_premium)+desc,geodist(listing_location) asc
```

My question here is:

- can I somehow map listing_premium to a 0 or 1
- or can I include an if statement in the sort
- or can I use copyField in the schema to create a generated field converting listing_premium to listing_premium_int

Much obliged!

Comment: I'm not familiar with this system, but can't you simply say something like `listing_premium ? 1 : 0`?

Comment: Brendan - you're right. i have rectified the situation :)

Answer (score 0):

The values for boolean might not be 0 and one. You can use the if() function to choose values based on that.

This expression:

```
if(listing_premium,1,0)
```

returns 1 if listing_premium is true and 0 if it is false.

Comment: I tried that as well, but I can't make it work within a sort:

    &sort=mul(map(geodist(listing_location),0.0001,25,1,0),if(listing_premium,1,0))

exception:
    Can't determine Sort Order: 'mul(map(geodist(listing_location),1,25,1,0),if(listing_premium,1,0)) desc

Do you have an example of an if-statement in a sort?

Comment: Sorry, I've done this sort of thing in the boost parameter in edismax, but not in sort. You might want to try boost, that mixes your score with the relevance score.